# webGL contour color plot on 3D model

Tags: webgl

I am working on software which is visualising engineering data on a surface of 3D model as color maps. For this I am using WebGL. At the moment I was able to display colors on surface of 3D model. 
But now I need to improve visualisation to make sharp transitions between colors (without color interpolation on a surface of triangles). 
I am not sure how to do it efficiently.

smooth contours plot

[image]

sharp contours plot

[image]

Comment: So right now you are setting the color as part of the vertex data?

Comment: yes exactly, colors are defined per each vertex of triangle

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this? I've found this project that has implemented similar but am finding it hard to decipher the shaders https://mbq.me/blog/webgl-weather-globe/

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. You have not provided enough information to understand how your colors are chosen/computed in the first place.

I can only guess of a couple of solutions that might fit your description

1. Post process with a posterization type of technique

   You could do a simple

   ```
   gl_FragColor.rgb = floor(gl_FragColor.rgb * numLevels) / numLevels;
   ```

   Or you could do it in some color space like

   ```
   // convert to HSV
   vec3 hsv = rgb2hsv(gl_FragColor.rgb);

   // quantize hue only
   hsv.x = floor(hsv.x * numLevels) / numLevels;

   // concert back to RGB
   gl_FragColor.rgb = hsv2rgb(hsv);
   ```

   Or you could also do this in your 3D shader, it doesn't have to be post process.

   You can find rgb2hsv and hsv2rgb [here](https://github.com/greggman/hft-utils/blob/64bfc752c5563d726452ad7b0982eff3ed8436c7/dist/sprite.js#L73) but of course you could use some other color space.

Example:

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const v3 = twgl.v3;
// used to generate colors
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = 1;
ctx.canvas.height = 1;

const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec3 normal;

  // note: there is no reason this has to come from an attrbute (per vertex)
  // it could just as easily come from a texture used in the fragment shader
  // for more resolution

  attribute vec4 color;

  uniform mat4 projection;
  uniform mat4 modelView;
  
  varying vec3 v_normal;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  
  void main () {
    gl_Position = projection * modelView * position;
    v_normal = mat3(modelView) * normal;
    v_color = color;
  }
`;
const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  
  varying vec3 v_normal;
  varying vec4 v_color;
  
  uniform float numLevels;
  uniform vec3 lightDirection;

  vec3 rgb2hsv(vec3 c) {
    vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
    vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));
    vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));

    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
    float e = 1.0e-10;
    return vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);
  }

  vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c) {
    c = vec3(c.x, clamp(c.yz, 0.0, 1.0));
    vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
    vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
    return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
  }

  void main() {
    vec3 hsv = rgb2hsv(v_color.rgb);
    
    hsv.x = floor(hsv.x * numLevels) / numLevels;
    
    vec3 rgb = hsv2rgb(hsv);
    
    // fake light
    float light = dot(normalize(v_normal), lightDirection) * .5 + .5;
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb * light, v_color.a);
    
    // uncomment next line to see without hue quantization
    // gl_FragColor = v_color;
  }
`;
  
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const radius = 5;
const thickness = 2;
const radialDivisions = 32;
const bodyDivisions = 12;
// creates positions, normals, etc...
const arrays = twgl.primitives.createTorusVertices(
    radius, thickness, radialDivisions, bodyDivisions);

// add colors  for each vertex
const numVerts = arrays.position.length / 3;
const colors = new Uint8Array(numVerts * 4);
for (let i = 0; i < numVerts; ++i) {
  const pos = arrays.position.subarray(i * 3, i * 3 + 3);
  const dist = v3.distance([3, 1, 3 + Math.sin(pos[0])], pos);
  colors.set(hsla(clamp(dist / 10, 0, 1), 1, .5, 1), i * 4);
}
arrays.color = {
  numComponents: 4,
  data: colors,
};

// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each
// array in arrays
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
const halfHeight = 8;
const halfWidth = halfHeight * aspect;
const projection = m4.ortho(
  -halfWidth, halfWidth,
  -halfHeight, halfHeight,
  -2, 2);
const modelView = m4.identity();
m4.rotateX(modelView, Math.PI * .5, modelView);

gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

// calls gl.bindbuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
// for each attribute
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

// calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
  projection,
  modelView,
  numLevels: 8,
  lightDirection: v3.normalize([1, 2, 3]),
});

// calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

function hsla(h, s, l, a) {
  ctx.fillStyle = `hsla(${h * 360 | 0},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%,${a})`;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
  return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
}

function clamp(v, min, max) {
  return Math.min(max, Math.max(min, v));
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

2. Render in 1 channel, use a lookup table

   In this case you'd make an Nx1 texture with your N colors. Then in your shader you'd just compute a gray scale (it's not clear how you're coloring things now) and use that to look up a color from your texture

   ```
   uniform sampler2D lookupTable;  // Nx1 texture set to nearest filtering

   float gray = whateverYourDoingNow();
   vec4 color = texture2D(lookupTable, vec2((gray, 0.5);

   // apply lighting to color
   ...
   ```

Example:

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const v3 = twgl.v3;

const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec3 normal;
  
  // note: there is no reason this has to come from an attrbute (per vertex)
  // it could just as easily come from a texture used in the fragment shader
  // for more resolution

  attribute float hotness;  // the data value 0 to 1
  
  uniform mat4 projection;
  uniform mat4 modelView;
  
  varying vec3 v_normal;
  varying float v_hotness;
  
  void main () {
    gl_Position = projection * modelView * position;
    v_normal = mat3(modelView) * normal;
    v_hotness = hotness;
  }
  `;
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  
  varying vec3 v_normal;
  varying float v_hotness;
  
  uniform float numColors;
  uniform sampler2D lookupTable;
  uniform vec3 lightDirection;
  
  void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(lookupTable, vec2(v_hotness, 0.5));
    
    // fake light
    float light = dot(normalize(v_normal), lightDirection) * .5 + .5;
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb * light, color.a);
  }
  `;
  
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  
  const radius = 5;
  const thickness = 2;
  const radialDivisions = 32;
  const bodyDivisions = 12;
  // creates positions, normals, etc...
  const arrays = twgl.primitives.createTorusVertices(
      radius, thickness, radialDivisions, bodyDivisions);
      
  // add a hotness value, 0 <-> 1, for each vertex
  const numVerts = arrays.position.length / 3;
  const hotness = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numVerts; ++i) {
    const pos = arrays.position.subarray(i * 3, i * 3 + 3);
    const dist = v3.distance([3, 1, 3 + Math.sin(pos[0])], pos);
    hotness[i] = clamp(dist / 10, 0, 1);
  }
  arrays.hotness = {
    numComponents: 1,
    data: hotness,
  };

  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each
  // array in arrays
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);
  
  const colors = [
     255,   0,   0, 255,  // red
     255, 150,  30, 255,  // orange
     255, 255,   0, 255,  // yellow
       0, 210,   0, 255,  // green
       0, 255, 255, 255,  // cyan
       0,   0, 255, 255,  // blue
     160,  30, 255, 255,  // purple
     255,   0, 255, 255,  // magenta
  ];
  // calls gl.createTexture, gl.texImage2D, gl.texParameteri
  const lookupTableTexture = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    src: colors,
    width: colors.length / 4,
    wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
    minMag: gl.NEAREST,   // comment this line out to see non hard edges
  });
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const halfHeight = 8;
  const halfWidth = halfHeight * aspect;
  const projection = m4.ortho(
    -halfWidth, halfWidth,
    -halfHeight, halfHeight,
    -2, 2);
  const modelView = m4.identity();
  m4.rotateX(modelView, Math.PI * .5, modelView);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  // calls gl.bindbuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  // for each attribute
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    projection,
    modelView,
    lookupTable: lookupTableTexture,
    lightDirection: v3.normalize([1, 2, 3]),
  });
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  
  
  function clamp(v, min, max) {
    return Math.min(max, Math.max(min, v));
  }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am also looking into using texture but as I answered above due to huge size of structure, and necessary resolution down to several millimeters I afraid I might end up with huge texture.
Currently I am looking into subdividing each triangle into 6 subtriangles, and use colors per vertex to create color map.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding how the second solution doesn't solve your problem. You can set the vertices colors to a specific color by using `hotness = (desiredColorIndex + .5) / numColors`. Or if you want you could also instead of using values 0 to 1 you could use specific color numbers and do the math in the shader.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be add the `flat` [interpolation modifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers) to your color attribute, as described in [this](https://www.geeks3d.com/20130514/opengl-interpolation-qualifiers-glsl-tutorial/) tutorial. This will prevent color values from beeing interpolated, so each triangle will end up with only one color (the one specified in the first of the three vertices).
Sadly I couldn't find anything about its webgl support, but you might as well try it out to see if it works.

If it doesn't work or you don't want the inividual triangles to be visible, you could also [load the color data to a texture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL) and retrieve the color of each pixel in the fragment shader. There would still be some interpolation depending on the texture size though (similar to how an image becomes blurry when scaled up).

Comment: thanks, I am looking into using texture, but there is a problem that, engineering structure might be 30- 50 meters, in biggest size and with this I need to have resolution to couple of millimiters (thickness om metal plates), I am afraid that this might result in huge texture.

Comment: It's not like using a texture will result in more data  - all the color data has to be transfered to the gpu anyways, and I'm quite sure most gpus can handle large textures better than they can handle large vertex buffer objects (which would be needed for this amount of precision with per-vertex-color).

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you probably don't need such a high precision for all parts of the model - a large area with very little change in color could be expressed by a very small section of the texture scaled up over the entire area.